# Need to copy a range which has multiple columns till the last used row

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I'm looking for a bit of code which selects the range from cell **A2** across till column AD, and then down till the last used row

Comment: Have you tried `UsedRange` and `Offset`. A dynamic named range will do the trick too.

Comment: see here for methods on finding the last row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
Sub my_code()

    lastrow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, 30)).Select

End Sub
```